# Django: use clean URLs with HTTP GET

Tags: python, django, http-get

I have a form in django, which looks something like this (after it has been rendered):

```
<form action="/app/detail/" method="get">
  <p><label for="id_detail">Choose which items to view:</label>
  <select multiple="multiple" id="id_items" name="items">
     <option value="23">Item 23</option>
     <option value="18">Item 18</option>
     <option value="22">Item 22</option>
  </select></p>
  <input type="submit" value="View" />
</form>
```

The associated url conf (in `app`) includes this pattern:

```
url(r'^detail/$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

The URL to access the detailed view ends up looking something like this (depending which of the options were selected in the mult-selection box:

```
http://hostname/app/detail/?items=23&items=18&items=22
```

In `views.py`, I can then use `request.GET.getlist('items')` to get whichever items were selected. Is there a way to do all of this so the URL appears cleaner without the `?param=value&` in the URL? [Django's URL dispatcher documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/) discusses clean looking URLs, but those examples are mostly URLs that are hierarchical in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url you just described is how parameters are passed by `GET` method. You could for sure use the base url, but change your form to use `POST` method instead. `POST` parameters are not passed through url, so it's most likely what you need. Look at django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) for details.